# Lua: how use all tables in table

Tags: syntax, lua, lua-table

```
positions = {
--table 1
[1] = {pos = {fromPosition = {x=1809, y=317, z=8},toPosition = {x=1818, y=331, z=8}}, m = {"100 monster"}},
--table 2
[2] = {pos = {fromPosition = {x=1809, y=317, z=8},toPosition = {x=1818, y=331, z=8}}, m = {"100 monster"}},
-- table3
[3] = {pos = {fromPosition = {x=1809, y=317, z=8},toPosition = {x=1818, y=331, z=8}}, m = {"100 monster"}}
}

    tb = positions[?]--what need place here?

for _,x in pairs(tb.m) do --function
    for s = 1, tonumber(x:match("%d+")) do
    pos = {x = math.random(tb.pos.fromPosition.x, tb.pos.toPosition.x), y = math.random(tb.pos.fromPosition.y, tb1.pos.toPosition.y), z = tb.pos.fromPosition.z}
    doCreateMonster(x:match("%s(.+)"), pos)
    end
    end
```

Here the problem, i use tb = positions[1],  and it only for one table in "positions" table. But how apply this function for all tables in this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Lua very well but you could loop over the table:

```
for i = 0, table.getn(positions), 1 do
     tb = positions[i]
     ...
end
```

Sources : 
http://lua.gts-stolberg.de/en/schleifen.php and http://www.lua.org/pil/19.1.html

Comment: Tested. it returns: attempt to index local 'tb' (a nil value) I will test this code with diff variations, becouse i dont have any idea why it return nil to me.

Comment: Solved:                                                             `for i,x in ipairs(positions) do
tb=positions[i] end`

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over `positions` with a numerical `for`.

Note that, unlike Antoine Lassauzay's answer, the loop starts at **1** and not **0**, and uses the `#` operator instead of `table.getn` (deprecated function in Lua 5.1, removed in Lua 5.2).

```
for i=1,#positions do
  tb = positions[i]
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use the pairs() built-in. there isn't any reason to do a numeric for loop here.

```
for index, position in pairs(positions) do
    tb = positions[index]
    -- tb is now exactly the same value as variable 'position'
end
```